# WP_Query orderby author__in

Tags: wp-query, order

I use WP_Query to get author posts with author ids array order. But it is not getting with true order.

```
$user_ids = array( 10, 11, 12, 13 );

$args = array(
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'post_type'      => 'custom-posts',
    'posts_per_page' => - 1,
    'author__in'     => $user_ids,
    'orderby'        => 'author',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
);
```

But it is getting like this:

```
user11 -> Post 1
user11 -> Post 2
user13 -> Post 1
user13 -> Post 2
user13 -> Post 3
user10 -> Post 1
user12 -> Post 1
user12 -> Post 2
```

I want this (With array order):

```
user10 -> Post 1
user11 -> Post 1
user11 -> Post 2
user12 -> Post 1
user12 -> Post 2
user13 -> Post 1
user13 -> Post 2
user13 -> Post 3
```